# how to change all the ethereum blocks from C drive to D drive on windows?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain

I have just finished downloading the ethereum blockchain data with the `go` client but my `c` drive is full, however I have 900 gigabytes of free space on `d` drive.

how can I make my blockchain data to `d` drive without starting downloading them from scratch again as they took me a month to download them ?

I also want to know does the `go` client will keep syncronizing automatically or I have to do something ?

I am new to ethereum.

thanks in advance

Comment: I read it but I don't know how to copy the data of blocks so I can then make the link to it ? I don't know how or the location of the data ? I am new to ethereum

Comment: The answer linked to gives the location: `C:\User\Username\AppData\Roaming\Ethereum` You can copy the blockchain using Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did something similar on Windows.

I used Windows Explorer and moved the folder and then created a Windows Junction or hard link.  You need to stop any program that is accessing the folder that you want to move.

I don't know what folders/drives you have, but should be something like this:

If the folder occupying all the space was located at
C:\programfiles\ethereum\mydata

1. Move mydata to J:\Ethereum\mydata
2. Now create a Windows junction (or hard link) so that whichever program is trying to find MyData will find it at its new location.

The junction has to be created in the folder where the data used to exist.

2a. Open a Command Prompt as an administrator
2b. Navigate to C:\programfiles\ethereum:
    cd C:\programfiles\ethereum\

2c. Now create the junction:
    mklink /D mydata J:\Ethereum\mydata

2C. Here is the same as above, just trying to make it a little cleared:
    mklink /D C:\programfiles\ethereum\mydata J:\Ethereum\mydata

3. Now create a random text file inside of J:\Ethereum\mydata
4. Then navigate to C:\programfiles\ethereum\mydata and make sure that you can see the text file.

If you can see it, you are done.

Just simply start the program, and it will start using the new location without knowing it was moved.

The junction is also permanent, it will stay until you delete the folder (junction) that you created on the C: drive

Comment: and whenever the geth sync more blocks the blocks will be added to the new location ?

Comment: Yes, it was created at the operating system level.  As far as Windows is concerned, they are both the same now.  Create a new text file to try it out.  The file should be visible from both places the C: where the data used to exist and the new drive (whatever drive letter you chose),